Comparision tool with react supportive library
1.Is there react supportive tool or library to show differences in a table,text,json or string or any freeware or licensed tool which can be integrated with react.
We have tried libraries like react-diff-view, react-diff-viewer, jsdiff but no package is showing differences for a table.
I want if I update, delete or add values of any object so it can show the differences in a table with old and new value.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
